# stop $http.success when status code is greater than 300

Tags: angularjs

in my application i handle general http error using htto interceptor , i get the status code when  it is greater or equall to 400 which means there is error either client side or server side  i broadcast an event and i have handler on app.run which is subscribed to event , 
,

the problem is $http.success is always running and i cant tell the angular to stop continuing controller method

below is simplified version of app

Interceptor

```
angular.module('starter.Aop', [])
    .factory('AuthInspector', ['$rootScope', '$injector', function AuthInspector($rootScope, $injector) {
        var service = {
            request: function (config) {
                var authToken = window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authToken;
                return config
            },
            responseError: function (response) {

                if (statusCode >= 400) {
                    $rootScope.$emit('someThingWrong')
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

                return response
            }
        };
        return service;
  }]);
```

app.run

```
.run(function ($timeout, $ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, $cordovaPushV5, $cordovaNetwork, $ionicPopup) {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                        $rootScope.$on('someThingWrong', function () {
                            console.log('someThingWrong')
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return;
                        })
```

controller

```
       $scope.logout = function () {
                         $http.post(serverConfig.serverUrl + "/api/account/logoutx").success(function (res) {
                             console.log('methode is successed')
                             //window.localStorage.removeItem('authToken');
                             //window.loclaStorage.removeItem('userFullName');
                         })
                     }
```

console.log('methode is successed') is allways runnign

how can i stop angular from continuing  controller method ?

Comment: greater than 300 doesn't mean there is an error. 3xx codes are for redirects. 4xx and 5xx are for errors. And angular deals with them natively. Why do you reinvent HTTP, instead of sticking to the spec? Use the appropriate status codes to signal errors.

Comment: ok , whethere 300 or =>400 m the question is how to handle execution

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Angular already takes care of error response, and **will** reject the promise if the status is an error status. Note, BTW, that success() and error() are deprecated for a loooong time, and will be removed in angular 1.6. Use then().

Comment: if you look at code , there is line in .success of my controller , console.log('methode is successed') , it is always running , even if status ocde is greater than 400 , i also used then . still it runs console.log('methode is successed') when there is error

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the issue, in a plnkr. Here's one, but as you see, it doesn't reproduce the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/XGhSia9A23ocLiDvPkj5?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AuthInspector` is **converting** rejections to successes.

To properly chain a rejection from an response error handler, use a `throw` statement, or `return $q.reject(error)`:

```
angular.module('starter.Aop', [])
    .factory('AuthInspector', function AuthInspector($q,$rootScope) {
        var service = {
            request: function (config) {
                var authToken = window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authToken;
                return config
            },
            responseError: function onReject(response) {

                if (response.status >= 400) {
                    $rootScope.$emit('someThingWrong')
                    //event.preventDefault();
                }

                //return response;
                throw response;
                //OR
                //return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
        return service;
  });
```

Returning a response to a rejection handler **converts** the rejection to a success.

Another common problem is rejection handlers which **omit** any `throw` or `return` statement. In that case, the handler returns `undefined` to the `$q` service; the rejection is **converted** to a success with subsequent success handlers getting invoked with `undefined` as the response argument.

Comment: i already used $q.reject , but id didnt know i can uses throw also.thanks a lot.